How do I link to an elements in the Elements panel from my own developed panel in chrome extension
I created my own chrome extension. One thing it does is inspect the HTML. I am passing the new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document) through chrome.runtime.sendMessage from the content script to devtools panel. Let me know if I can do that easier. But now that I DOMParser the string to get a document and do some work with it, I would like to be able to link to certain xpaths in the Elements panel, when the user clicks on a button or a link I generate in this custom panel. How can I link to a specific element in the Elements panel?
